# Creating New Table Removes Previous Table Created

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio

I'm creating a table on a local database with the following code:

```
string connectionString = GaryTrade.Properties.Settings.Default.AssetsDBConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection dbConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    dbConnection.Open();

    // Create the table in the database.
    string cmdString = "CREATE TABLE " + tableName + "(timestamp date);";
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cmdString, dbConnection);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    
    dbConnection.Close();
}
```

which works, and I can see it in SQL Server Object Explorer, but when I exit the program and run the same code again with a different tableName, the older table is replaced by the new table. How do I make it so the tables I create persist after I add new ones?

Edit: my connection string is "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\AssetsDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

Comment: Your application must be rolling back the transaction (or at least failing to commit it) There is nothing in SQL Server (or the code you have shown) that would result in a table being removed.

Comment: When I exit the program and run it again, but not run the code above, the table I most recently created can be seen in the explorer. Doesn't that mean the transaction was committed? Do I need to execute a "commit" command?

Comment: Hmmm... what are you using for `tableName`?

Comment: I'm using stock names like "AMD" or "AAPL".

Comment: Based on the code provided, that is impossible. There must be something else happening. Try the same command in SSMS, create table1, then create table2 - you'll end up with both of them.

Comment: What is SSMS? Sorry I'm new to this database stuff.

Comment: hmmm when I execute manual queries in the explorer like, "create table AAPL(timestamp date)", it works just as expected.

Comment: Side note: It seems like you're doing something fundamentally wrong anyway. If your plan is to store stock values, do not store them in one table per company each but store them in exactly one table, including a column that designates the company. Tables in relational database aren't spreadsheets.

Comment: Do you recreate the db every time you run the program any chance?

Comment: @ilkerkaran No, creating the db is not part of the code.

Comment: It sounds like Visual Studio is overwriting AssetsDB.mdf (and so resetting its contents) each time you run your project. If it weren't then the second and subsequent runs of your program would error because you cannot `CREATE TABLE` over an existing table (you have to drop it first). Have you checked the properties of AssetsDB.mdf via Solution Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by replacing this line:

```
string connectionString = MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString;
```

with

```
string connectionString = "Data Source = (LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename ="
                    + "G:\\programs\\Visual Studio Workspace\\MyProject\\MyProject\\Database1.mdf; Integrated Security = True";
```

It seems when you create a database file, it puts it on 2 locations:

1. \MyProject\MyProject\Database1.mdf
2. \MyProject\MyProject\bin\Debug\Database1.mdf

MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default.Database1ConnectionString was pointed to `|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf` and that doesn't work.